# What submersible adhesive is watertight and durable?

Tags: adhesive

I am creating an overflow pipe for a rain barrel. Will be creating my own 3D-printed "flange" connector. Half of it will be submerged. Its "flaps" need to be glued to the interior wall of the rain barrel. What kind of adhesive would I use for this? It needs to be impermeable to water (water-resistant) and not degrade over time in the water. As an adhesive, it needs to be strong enough to withstand some accidental bumps of the overflow hose which will be connected to the connector.

Thanks!

Comment: As asked this is a product recommendation question and may get closed. If you edit it to ask, how to waterproof a connection to my rain barrel,  it will be allowed.

Comment: You haven't told us what the rain barrels are. That's critical. Plastics are notoriously difficult to seal and bond.

Comment: Also, I'd not rely on adhesive for this. A riveted, double-gasketed connection would be much more durable.

Comment: What material are you 3D printing with? What kind of plastic is the barrel made of? Would a 'universal' plumbing cement (ABS/PVC/CPVC) be compatible with both?

Comment: PLA and ABS need UV protection, else it won't last long outdoors.

Answer (score 3):

I would think a marine grade epoxy should do the trick for you. It would definitely be waterproof and it's made to hold up under the stresses of a moving boat, and to hold up to salt water which is much harsher than the fresh water in your rain barrel

Comment: Will it stick to plastic?

Comment: Fair enough question. I'd imagine that some will.

Comment: The problem with marine grade epoxy is they usually get hard or all the ones I have used on my boats do as a sealer ok but 2 pieces that may get whacked? It might work.

Comment: After a bit of digging, it seems that some marine grade epoxies do adhere to plastics. Some indicate a "variety of plastics". The OP would need to ask the mfgr about the specific plastics he has in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Try flex seal they show it on TV filling gaps in a water tank, when it cures it is a rubber like material.

Answer (score 1):

I used some of those large blue plastic containers as rain butts but I used these brass connectors and they worked a treat, for 22mm pipe but other sizes are available.

[image]

I have always known them as tank connectors but that may not be the only name.

Comment: What is the generic name for this type of connector?

Comment: I did an image search on "tank flange" and found the same picture. (actually a slightly different picture)